# Connect to Bluetooth HSP/HFP service from android

Tags: android, bluetooth, pybluez, hfp, bluetoothheadset

I'm trying to build an application which allows me to answer incoming phone calls from my PC, so far, i was able to advertise a service using Pybluez in Python.

Now, How can i connect to that service from android?

Comment: What OS is your PC running? If it is Linux, then there is an example in the BlueZ source tree: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-hfp

Comment: Yes, i am using linux and i have no problem with the server part, my problem is the client connection(Android-Java)